# Maggid of Caro?

Tags: jewish-books

I found a copy of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1163148539) on Amazon, has anyone read it?  If so, what is it about?

I have heard Rabbi Yosef Karo wrote a book about his experience with his Maggid but I’m not sure if this is the same book.

Comment: This looks like a translation of Maggid Meisharim

Answer (score 3):

According to [this contemporary review](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-mental-science/article/abs/the-maggid-of-caro-by-hirsch-loeb-gordon-md-new-york-pardes-publishing-house-inc-the-shoulson-press-1949-pp-396-illus-182/C88806F584DBD89777069F16C6B7DD15) published in the *Journal of Mental Science* in 1949 when the first edition of this book came out, The Maggid of Caro includes detailed descriptions of Rav Yosef Caro's family, religious, and cultural background, as well as the times and places where he lived.

It also includes translated excerpts from his "secret diary" regarding the maggid. As such this book would appear not to be a verbatium translation of Caro's work.  [image: here].